# When rain falls, is it safe to say that night isnt laylatul qadr?

Tags: ramadan, laylat-al-qadr

Its famous that one of laylatul qadr sign was that night is calm. Not too hot nor too cold. So when rain fall its safe to say that night isnt laylatul qadr?

Comment: Just because it was on a calm night doesn't necessarily mean it *always* will be on a calm night.

Comment: I thought it was the opposite? If it does rain, then that’s a sign for the night of qadr

Answer (score 3):

This does not seem logically possible.

- There are regions of the world which have a [wet season](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wet_season) and [monsoons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsoon) (and [tropical monsoons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_monsoon_climate)), during which it can rain near continuously for months on end.

  Have you ever watched the movie [Forrest Gump](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109830/)?

  > *Forrest Gump*: One day it started raining, and it didn't quit for four months. We been through every kind of rain there is. Little bitty stingin' rain... and big ol' fat rain. Rain that flew in sideways. And sometimes rain even seemed to come straight up from underneath. Shoot, it even rained at night...

  This is actually realistic.  So, in a given place, it could rain every day during the last days of Ramadan.
- Another logical problem is that on any given day, it will almost certainly be raining somewhere around the world.  This would imply that [laylatul qadr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laylat_al-Qadr) would need to be on different nights in different places.

Answer (score 0):

Asalom Alai kom 
I know this post is from a few years ago but I just came across it.

RAIN IS ACTUALLY A SIGN OF LAYATUL WEDED.

The first of them or number one is that Laylatul Qadr is a peaceful, tranquil quiet night. Within that night or the night of Laylatul Qadr you do not hear the barking of dogs, or the sound of the cockerel.

The second sign is that in Laylatul Qadr the people experience a pleasant breeze or a pleasant wind which they enjoy which they like.

Thirdly, in Laylatul Qadr there is rain. This is one of the signs of Laylatul Qadr that during the night of Laylatul Qadr the rain falls.

Fourthly, is that when the sun rises on the following morning the disc of the sun is seen without strong rays or is without any rays. The disc is a clear disc when it rises in the morning

Comment: This post would profit from evidences supporting your claims. See [answer].